# Как реализовать сохранение фрагмента радио потока с сайта?

Tags: javascript, html5

Господа, парой строчек кода, как в приведенном ниже примере, можно реализовать вещание радио. На стандартной Audio панели есть кнопка скачать (стрелка вниз), если бы в место ссылки на радио поток, как в данном примере была бы ссылка на аудио файл, то он бы просто скачался и все, вопроса нет... А как реализовать скачивание одной песни или какого-нибудь фрагмента радио потока?  Если в данной реализации кода нажать  кнопку "СКАЧАТЬ", то скачивание начнется, ни как не могу сообразить как реализовать остановку скачивания.

Есть такая возможность, при скачивании потока, выдернуть (перенести в другую папку или диск, скопировать) его в другое место и остановить скачивание и и этот скаченный файл остается, это все в ручную...

Вопрос: как не вручную реализовать остановку скачивания ?

Дополняю вопрос примером на JS без тега audio, а с объектом new Audio.
В втором примере  тоже простой кусок кода на js которая запускает воспроизведения Радио потока. Play воспроизводим, Pause останавливаем.
А как сделать так, что бы нажав кнопку  Radio Save Start начать запись, а нажав кнопку Radio Save Stop остановить запись  и сохранить

```js
var radio = new Audio();
radio.src = "http://chanson.hostingradio.ru:8041/chanson128.mp3?";

document.querySelector('#radioPlay').onclick = function() {
  radio.play()
}
document.querySelector('#radioStop').onclick = function() {
  radio.pause()
}
document.querySelector('#radioSaveStart').onclick = function() {
  /*как тут начать запись*/
}
document.querySelector('#radioSaveStop').onclick = function() {

  /* и как тут закончить запись и сохранить*/
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://chanson.hostingradio.ru:8041/chanson128.mp3?">
</audio>


<div id="radioPlay">Play</div>
<div id="radioStop">Stop</div>
<div id="radioSaveStart">Radio Save Start</div>
<div id="radioSaveStop">Radio Save Stop</div>
```

Comment: Чтобы отдельные композиции получить нужно скачанный файл вручную разрезать на куски по границам композиций, думаю вряд ли где-то можно для автоматизации получить информацию о границах композиций. Относительно прерывания скачивания можно поступить так - начать скачивать в браузере, а когда нужно прервать то вручную файл частично скачанный скопировать в другое место, а скачивание можно отменить, тогда скачиваемый файл исчезнет (браузеры обычно не оставляют недокачанные файлы) а скопированный файл останется.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul, вот запусти пример, и увидишь кнопку стрелка вниз, это скачать...  когда начинаешь качать, если это просто муз файл, то он скачается и все...  а если это радио, то тоже начинает качать, а вот как остановить?  вот в чем вопрос...  что бы файл частично скаченный куда-то скопировать, его же надо остановить? а как?

Comment: Ну я только что попробовал это сделать в Хроме. Начал скачивание, потом в процессе скачивания скопировал файл, т.е. не останавливал его а прямо качаемый скопировал и всё, отменил скачивание, в итоге оригинал исчез а дубликат остался. Кстати можно использовать [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) это консольный качальщик, его когда прерываешь скачивание то он оставляет файл скачанный частично.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul, погоди я щас вопрос дополню

Comment: Ну я же не могу пользователю, посетителю сайта предложить - "Батенька, когда вы будете скачивать понравившуюся вам песню, прослушивая радио, будьте любезны, откройте папочку в которую вы скачивайте фрагмент, перенесите его в другую папку, отмените скачивание, потом уберите  из название последний кусок до точки, потом перенесите куда хотите "?

Comment: Этот веб ресурс ваш? Вы можете разрешить для него `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`?

Comment: @Zergatul, и что эьл даст?

Comment: @Air Всё равно из этого потока отдельную композицию не скачаешь, если вы хотите на сайте предоставлять отдельные композиции тогда нужно вам автоматически или вручную делать предобработку данных где-то на сервере, т.е. разбивать на композиции например. А если вам нужно сделать у клиента просто возможность скачивания из этого потока какого-то определённого объёма по времени, тогда я думаю нужно JavaScript задействовать и в нём на клиенте обрабатывать нажатие кнопок Старт/Стоп и прерывать поток, у JavaScript есть возможность сохранять нужный объём в файл или прерывать скачивание.

Comment: @Air Это даст возможность скачать часть потока в файл через `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: @Zergatul, я знаю что и как можно сделать с этой частью... как мне остановить запись, что бы получить эту часть?

Comment: Доступ к серверу вещания есть? Тут, мне кажется вариант обрывать стрим с сервера. т.е. начали запись стрим пошёл качаться, закончили запись - послали запрос на сервер, сервер стрим для пользователя обрубил, и пользователь перегрузил стрим. Не уверен что можно управлять скачивалкой, когда ей прекратить. скачивалка тупо берёт данные их потока, пока они есть.

Comment: @Чад, объясни поподробнее?

Comment: @Air, что именно?

Comment: @Чад По поводу твоего последнего коммита, что такое обрывать стрим, и как это реализовать...  я в JS новичек

Comment: @air - это надо делать на стороне сервера трансляции.

Comment: [Web_Audio_API](https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/), еще [Web_Audio_API](http://html5.by/blog/audio/),  [Recorderjs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs)

Comment: @Даниил, благодарю...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как реализовать сохранение фрагмента радио потока с сайта?

Ровно так же, как и скачивание абсолютно любых других файлов с вашего сервера, а будет ли это фрагмент потока с радио или видеоклип - дело десятое.

> А как реализовать скачивание одной песни

А где у радиопотока есть такая сущность (абстракция) как "песня"? В радиопотоке может говорить ведущий с утра до вечера, ни одной песни не прозвучит... Что же тогда должна будет скачивать программа, которая о таком не знает?

> ни как не могу сообразить как реализовать остановку скачивания.

Никак. Начать хотя бы с того, что скачивание может быть начато не самим браузером, а каким-либо внешним приложением. А доступа к приложению, конечно же, у вас нет.

Но, как тут уже сказали, можно со стороны сервера оборвать соединение. Качалки на это могут отреагировать по разному, но в общем и целом, они посчитают, что файл уже скачан целиком, тем самым сохранят некий ошметок. В айскасте есть даже специальный метод, который позволяет кильнуть клиента, а вот понять кого надо килять - сложно, по ошибке можно пристрелить поток браузера.

> Дополняю вопрос примером на JS без тега audio, а с объектом new Audio.

Совершенно не важно как вы инстанцируете этот примитивный плеер аудиопотоков. Через тег или еще через что-то. Функции сохранения, которая вам так нужна, в нем просто нет.

> А как сделать так, что бы нажав кнопку Radio Save Start начать запись,
>   а нажав кнопку Radio Save Stop остановить запись и сохранить
>
> Ну я же не могу пользователю, посетителю сайта предложить - "Батенька,
>   когда вы будете скачивать понравившуюся вам песню, прослушивая радио,
>   будьте любезны, откройте папочку в которую вы скачивайте фрагмент,
>   перенесите его в другую папку, отмените скачивание, потом уберите из
>   название последний кусок до точки, потом перенесите куда хотите "?

Для этого надо писать приложения на нормальном языке программирования, а не том, что маркетологи так яро скармливают в своих докладах. В частности, в этом языке должна быть явно прописана работа с сетью, подключение к серверу, передача заголовков, прием байтиков, скармливание этих байтиков декодеру и файловому дескриптору, ну и прочие сложности и глупости, которые присущи устаревшим языкам программирования и которых нету в таком прекрасном языке как Джаваскрипт. Собственно, выше - написано как это сделать, просто вместе с декодером вы отправляете данные и в файл, но так как в "веб-платформе" всего этого нет, разделить все это не выйдет, то ничего не получится. Подробнее об этом можно почитать у Джоэла Спольски в его Законе дырявых абстракций. И или отказаться от идеи, или переписать свой проект на чем-то другом, хотя бы на загнивающем Adobe Flash, который все же является более жизнеспособной платформой, чем современный JS

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотите это сделать на стороне браузера. Дело в том что если вы запустили закачку, то управление этой закачкой скорее всего уже только у браузера и управлять ею через javascript нельзя.

Предлагаю сделать эту функцию на стороне сервера. При нажатии на кнопку сервер начинает скачивать файл, когда нажата кнопка прекратить сервер прекращает скачивать файл, и возвращает клиенту ссылку на скачивание через AJAX.

Либо скачивать не стандартной скачивалкой браузера, а через AJAX, тут нужно искать библиотеку для потоковой закачки файла. Или использовать стандартный `fetch`, в [этой статье](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/) написано что используя `fetch` можно иметь доступ к частично скачанному контенту, но как я понял эта функциональность `fetch` дорабатывается. [Тут](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#readablestream) описан стандарт для `fetch` `readable stream`.