# Inline-block не помещается в блок, что делать?

Tags: html, css

Нужно выстроить блоки в одну строку. И ширина у них должна быть 1/3 от родителя и рамка. И отступов между блоками быть не должно. Я вроде все сделал правильно, но третий блок вылезает снизу с новой строки. Что не так не пойму...

```css
.ex1 .variant1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
}

.ex1 .variant1 .red {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 10px black;
  margin: -5px;
}

.ex1 .variant1 .green {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 10px black;
  margin: -5px;
}

.ex1 .variant1 .blue {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 10px black;
  margin: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
  <div class="cols variant1">
    <div class="red">
      <h3>Погода</h3>
      <p>Сегодня солнечно</p>
    </div>
    <div class="green">
      <h3>Курс доллара</h3>
      <p>1 доллар США = 30,32 рубля</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
      <h3>Сейчас в кино</h3>
      <p>Пятый элемент (2002)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отступы между элементами с inline-block](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/609992/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81-inline-block)

Comment: Там про отступы говорится, а я их марджином убрал.

Comment: Значит твое решение не работает. Попробуй решения из вопроса дубликата

Comment: Так там и говорится про марджин

Comment: Так вроде получилось. Я марджин до 25 пикселей увеличил.

Comment: У тебя на самом деле проблема в бордере

Comment: _Так там и говорится про марджин_ - Ты выбрал один из самых сложных вариантов, попробуй другие :)

Comment: Какая? Слева кусок рамки пропал у меня. Но зато блоки в одну строку выстроились

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Устанавливается только одному элементу.

У элементов с `display:inline-block` остается значение `content-box`. Это означает, что размер границы не будет входить в рассчитанную ширину и будет идти сверху. Так как ширина границы довольно большая по сравнения с основной шириной сумма конечных размеров блоков больше 100% из-за этого происходит перенос.

Для решения можно установить `box-sizing: border-box;` для всех дивов, например так

```css
.ex1 div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ex1 .variant1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
}

.ex1 .variant1 .red {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 10px black;
}

.ex1 .variant1 .green {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 10px black;
}

.ex1 .variant1 .blue {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
  <div class="cols variant1">
    <div class="red">
      <h3>Погода</h3>
      <p>Сегодня солнечно</p>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="green">
      <h3>Курс доллара</h3>
      <p>1 доллар США = 30,32 рубля</p>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="blue">
      <h3>Сейчас в кино</h3>
      <p>Пятый элемент (2002)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Либо просто уменьшить размер границы:

```css
.ex1 .variant1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red;
}

.ex1 .variant1 .red {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 3px black;
  margin: -5px;
}

.ex1 .variant1 .green {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 3px black;
  margin: -5px;
}

.ex1 .variant1 .blue {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 3px black;
  margin: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
  <div class="cols variant1">
    <div class="red">
      <h3>Погода</h3>
      <p>Сегодня солнечно</p>
    </div>
    <div class="green">
      <h3>Курс доллара</h3>
      <p>1 доллар США = 30,32 рубля</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
      <h3>Сейчас в кино</h3>
      <p>Пятый элемент (2002)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ты не учел размет border.  border рисуется с наружи что бы border отрисоыввался изнутри box-sizing:border-box;

```css
.ex1 .variant1 {
  background: red;
}
.ex1 .variant1 .red {
box-sizing:border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 10px black;

}

.ex1 .variant1 .green {
box-sizing:border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 10px black;
  margin: -5px;
}

.ex1 .variant1 .blue {
box-sizing:border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.3%;
  border: solid 10px black;
  margin: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
  <div class="cols variant1">
    <div class="red">
      <h3>Погода</h3>
      <p>Сегодня солнечно</p>
    </div>
    <div class="green">
      <h3>Курс доллара</h3>
      <p>1 доллар США = 30,32 рубля</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
      <h3>Сейчас в кино</h3>
      <p>Пятый элемент (2002)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: _что бы border отрисоыввался изнутри box-sizing:border-box;_ - в css уже использовался _box-sizing:border-box_ в одном месте

Comment: забыл убрать, на кой он там без border ))

Comment: @Grundy, глянь на мой последний вопрос, может, что восоветуешь...

Comment: твой последний вопрос это какой?

Comment: @Grundy  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742356/Как-реализовать-сохранение-фрагмента-радио-потока-с-сайта