# Скрипт записи mp3 из браузера,на js

Tags: javascript

Приведите пожалуйста пример скрипта, который силами js  записывает mp3 файл при нажатие на кнопку в браузере пользователя

Comment: куда записывает? откуда записывает?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать сохранение фрагмента радио потока с сайта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/742356/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: ThisMan  Записать в браузере пользователя mp3 после выслать аяксом на сервер, что - то тип голосового сообщения в вк

Comment: Air пример приведенный там не работает, возможно гдет накосячил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека [Recorderjs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) Вам в помощь. С помощью неё можно записать звук с компьютера в формате WAV, а для конвертации в МП3 используют ещё другую библиотеку -lame.js. Я её найду чуть позже.

Comment: не работает  в файре, ток в гугле вроде...

Comment: Да, я забыл предупредить. В index.html даже где-то выводится, что требуется Google Chrome

Comment: никак нельзя еще другие клиенты присобачить?

Comment: Только что я пробовал в Опере-54, тоже работает.

Comment: Даже ради интереса установил Firefox. Да, пожалуй, он выдаёт ошибку **TypeError: navigator.getUserMedia is not a function**. И запрос разрешенния использовать микрофон не появляется. Т. е., не поддерживает работу с микшером звука, получается.

Comment: ну та ладно....

Comment: https://p5js.org/examples/sound-record-save-audio.html